# PHP - Change values in array result

Tags: php, arrays

I have part of a code:

```
$array = (json_encode($data, true));
```

which gives me a result of:

```
"["Id\tFirstName\tLastName\tDateOfBirth\tPhone\tAddress1\tAddress2\tCity\tState\tPostCode\tCountry\tEmail"]"
```

I need to post it in a filed of a database but it looks harder to view and read.

I would want to get result like

```
"{Id, FirstName , LastName, DateOfBirth, ...}"
```

It tried some functions like array_implode, array_replace but no success.

My $data content:

```
array:1 [
  0 => "Id\tFirstName\tLastName\tDateOfBirth\tPhone\tAddress1\tAddress2\tCity\tState\tPostCode\tCountry\tEmail"
```

1 => "Id\tAnna\tGreen\t199/12/12\t25413698\tMemoryLane\t..."

```
]
```

What can I try?

Comment: Maybe your JSON data isn't in a corrent format. Post the content of `$data`

Comment: can you show us $data before encoding?

Comment: What does `true` means at the place of the second argument of `json_encode`?

Comment: you dont use 'true' as second argument in json_encode, you can use it in json_decode if you want array as result

Comment: It respresents 'option' argument. I tried with it, it doesn't make any difference. @AterLux

Comment: Why array contais only 1 element? What result do you expect if there more?

Comment: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given. @Zeljka

Comment: you didnt understood me. I told you when you are using json_decode, second argument can be true, in json_encode second argument can be JSON_FORCE_OBJECT, JSON_HEX_QUOT, JSON_HEX_TAG, JSON_HEX_AMP, JSON_HEX_APOS, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK, JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR, JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT, JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR. I didnt told you to use json_decode, I was just trying to explain that in json_encode second argument cant be 'true'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.if you want results to be array of json strings

```
$results = [];
foreach($data as $dat){
    $results[] = json_encode(explode("\t", $dat));
}
var_dump($results);
```

2.if you want all results to be json string

```
$results = [];
foreach($data as $dat){
    $results[] = explode("\t", $dat);
}
var_dump(json_encode($results));
```

Old answer -> Before encoding, explode first value od array (string) by '\t' and after that encode array.

```
$data = explode("\t", $data[0]);
$results = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: How can I 'explode' multiple rows? When I use $data = explode("\t", $data);, without [0] it throws an error.  @Zeljka

Answer (score 0):

```
  // Example data
  $data = array(
      "Id\tFirstName\tLastName\tDateOfBirth\tPhone\tAddress1\tAddress2\tCity\tState\tPostCode\tCountry\tEmail",
      "May\tBe\tMore\tLines\tHere"
  );


  // Processing
  $a = $data;
  // Change all \t to comma and put { } around in each item
  array_walk($a, function(&$item) { $item = '{ ' .str_replace("\t", ', ', $item) . ' }'; });

  // combine all items into a line
  $result = implode(', ', $a);

  print($result);
  // { Id, FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, Phone, Address1, Address2, City, State, PostCode, Country, Email }, { May, Be, More, Lines, Here }
```

Comment: Wow. That solved my problem. Thanks a lot! @AterLux